# What is the purpose of the laws of mourning?

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, nine-days

There are generally accepted laws and customs regarding a mourner, whether mourning for a relative  or for the tragedy of the destruction of the bais hamikdash.  Examples include restriction from bathing and hair cutting.  What is the purpose of these halachos?  Is there a theme?  Some ideas might be:

- We are required to actualize our grief.
- Doing these actions give us a "geshmak" which makes us forget about our grief.

Are there any sources that address this?  Any ideas?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25118892#25118892

Answer (score 3):

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46539&st=&pgnum=27

The main purpose of Hilchos Aveilus is to remind us to do Teshuva.

Comment: More specifically what I was looking for was the part where he says that actions affect how we feel- so the laws help break our hearts.    Our goal is Teshuva.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Meir Spiegelman ([link](http://www.vbm-torah.org/3weeks/mshp.htm)) discusses this topic at length.  One of his themes is that practices of mourning are based partially in the laws of tum'a. Just like purifying ourselves brings us closer to G-d, when we feel a distance from Him, we act as though we were impure.  Examples include not bathing, washing clothes, cutting hair, wearing shoes, sitting on a chair, or lying on a bed.